# The inherent issue of domain, infrastructure and application layer coherency

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm in a pickle.

I'm working on a robust system, and it's cut into multiple microservices. 
The one I'm currently working on is a plain, simple live chat.

However, I'm thinking myself into inaction - trying to analyze and get the best outcome.

I have the following entities: `Channel` and `User`. 
`Channel` has many `Users`, which can be added via `Channel.AddUser` and are stored in `Channel.Users`. 
In a perfect scenario - `Channel.Users` would **always** contain all `Users` associated with that `Channel`. 

Now, the issue I'm having is - according to DDD, my domain should be as pure and as blissfully ignorant to the implementation details as possible - and this is totally achievable as long as my `Channels` and associated `Users` remain in RAM. 
But! As soon as I implement any sort of persistent storage - the whole principle of designing an isolated, unaffected by implementation domain falls apart - all because I can load my `Channel` without `Users` or with only first 10 of them etc. - which can affect things like: validation, business logic etc.

How does one handle this - is builiding domain around a specific "application" (in a general sense, not layer) the only way?

Answer (score 1):

> How does one handle this - is builiding domain around a specific "application" (in a general sense, not layer) the only way?

By thinking very carefully about where the real boundaries should be in your system.

You will typically want to deeply consider whether "Channel has Users" is the best way to model the relationship between the two entities.

Possibilities include:

- Channels should have collections of users.
- Channels should have collections of user identifiers, which point to users stored elsewhere
- Users should have channel pointer identifiers (which point to channels stored elsewhere
- The relationship between Channels and Users is not part of Channels or Users, but instead belongs to some Third Thing that we haven't considered here (is "subscription" a thing in your domain?)

Expressed another way: not all of the information accessed via a specific channel identifier is necessarily part of the same "aggregate".  If you are considering "lazy loading" of information, that's often a tell that there are (or at least were) opportunities to improve the partitioning of your data.

The key that you use to access the information is a less important consideration than which information is used together when making changes.

Comment: Hmm. Fetching and storing ids along with Channels sounds feasible to say the least, however this still leaves an open door for different variants of the same entity - one with 1, 10, 20 or even 0 out of n user ids fetched.